# spring-security writing a custom PermissionEvaluator - how to inject a DAO service?

Tags: permissions, constructor, spring-security, inject

I'm working with Spring-Security and I need to implement my own PermissionEvaluator (following the answer to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481869/spring-security-how-acl-grants-permissions).

However looking at the standard implementation `AclPermissionEvaluator` [here](http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/spring-security/blobs/3f70d79df5d7cb74db1c8347a705d49f6761fb04/acl/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/acls/AclPermissionEvaluator.java) I notice, that the DAO is set via the constructor.

If I declare my custom PermissionEvaluator like this:

```xml
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>

<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator">
        <beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.npacemo.permissions.SomePermissionsEvaluator"/>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

where do I get my DAO into the Evaluator so that I can access data? Can I inject it, meaning is the PermissionEvaluator Spring managed? Or how do I get my dataProvider into the Evaluator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just figured it out: The PermissionEvaluator is Spring managed, so

```
@Inject 
private PermissionManager permissionManager;
```

will work just fine.

---

**edit:**
For our project we'll implement our own PermissionResolver probably extending the standard Implementation:

```
public class OurPermissionEvaluator extends AclPermissionEvaluator{


    public CombinedPermissionEvaluator(AclService aclService) {
        super(aclService);
    }
```

and injecting a custom ACLService (following [this](http://grzegorzborkowski.blogspot.com/2008/10/spring-security-acl-very-basic-tutorial.html) tutorial)

```
public class OurAclServiceImpl implements AclService {
```

where we retrieve ACL information from our custom database structure.

To wire it all we'll follow the spring-security contacts example:

```
<b:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="path.to.OurPermissionEvaluator">
    <b:constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
</b:bean>
```

where aclService has to be declared thus:

```
  <bean id="aclService" class="path.to.OurAclServiceImpl">
     <constructor args here... >
  </bean>
```